# How to combine Backbone.Marionette and Backbone-Boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework, marionette, backbone-boilerplate

Are there any tutorials or insights in how to combine Backbone.Marionette and Backbone-Boilerplate? I am having trouble with this. The Marionette wiki for the integration is outdated and not finished.

Is it possible I can maintain the boilerplate module set-up, but also use Marionette views?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the views. You are not required to use all of marionette, just use the parts that you need. Unfortunately you will still have to bring all of marionette along for the ride - modules and application and all, though. This is something I want to make easier in the future... To just have the views or just have the Application structure,etc.

Comment: Ah that's what I thought. Since I'm not sure how to bring all of marionette over correctly, I think I'll just start with marionette for now.

Answer (score 1):

For another option, take a look at [Brunch](http://brunch.io)

It's an application builder/assembler which is distributed as a node module, so you can install it the standard node way using npm.

It will generate for you a boilerplate app, and then it will "compile" at your command all it's components to html/javascript/css. You can use default boilerplate like so

`brunch new your-project`

or use any of the many boilerplate apps (skeletons in brunch parlance) that you can examine at Brunch skeletons by means of

`brunch new your-project -s url-of-skeleton`

More up to the point of your question, you may find in the skeletons page two Marionette driven ones - it's worth noticing though, that none of them uses BBB - :

Brunch with MarionetteJS

and

[Brunch with Puppets](https://github.com/sandy98/brunch-with-puppets)

Even though you asked for tutorials, examining the code of the generated apps could prove highly educational. It did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application/11598371#11598371) is a starting point, it's not perfect, but it will help you get started.